# Multiple checkboxes with same id but only one works

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, fadein, fadeout

So my idea is that when i check the checkbox every div named .picpic fades out(except the filtered ones) and when i uncheck they fade back in. The problem is that this jQuery code works only on the first checkbox. Thank you for your ideas.

Checkboxes

```
<form>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="selectedv" value="a1"/> a1 </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="selectedv" value="a2" /> a2 </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="selectedv" value="a3" /> a3 </label>

  </form>
```

jQuery

If checkbox is checked every .picpic div fades out except the filtered ones and when unchecked they fade back in.

```
if(document.getElementById('selectedv').checked) {
$('.picpic').not($filteredResults).fadeOut(1000)
} else {
    $('.picpic').fadeIn(1000)();
}
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: You could always do it by class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got the solution i wanted.

- Used classes instead of ID's because ID's are supposed to be unique.
- If checkbox is checked it makes every div except the filtered ones
- fade out. If every checkbox is checked all of the divs are showing.

Checkboxes

```
    <form>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="selected v" value="a1"/> a1 </label>

        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="selected a" value="a2" /> a2 </label>

        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="selected z" value="a3" /> a3 </label> <br>

</form>
```

jquery

```
 if($('input.selected').is(':checked')) {
        $('.picpic').not($filteredResults).fadeOut(1000)
        $($filteredResults).fadeIn(1000)()
        } else {
            $('.picpic').fadeIn(1000)();
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/01o2pawk/1/

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementById` does just that: gets one element with that ID. The HTML specs don’t allow you to have more than one element for any ID.

In this instance you could switch to `class` or `name`.

Comment: Yes you are all correct VolcovMeter, Taplar and Dan Soper. I feel silly that i didn't come to this on my own. But now i ran into another problem. When i choose 2 checkboxes it should show both divs with given value in checkbox(example: i check checkbox 1 and 2 and it gives me divs with value a1 and a2.). But the divs that have dissapeared they dont appear back when i uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: I’d need to see more of your code, especially how $filteredResults is getting created. Have a look at your logic there.

Comment: Not exactly. If all 3 checkboxes are checked it should show all 3 different divs.

Comment: Oh yes. The chances I made don’t seem to have saved.

Comment: So i came up with this https://jsfiddle.net/01o2pawk/1/
Please let me know when you have better/shorter solution. I am very interested. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to style multiple elements using one text area try using classes rather than ids.